# Portal page for StackExchange sites

Tags: feature-request, status-completed

Wouldn't it be a good idea to propose a portal page where one could have an overview of existing sites and access them? Currently, it's hard to see which sites are launched, which are in beta, and which topics are not yet adressed.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Most of this information is already available:

Latest and most progressed beta proposals here: http://area51.stackexchange.com/

Top voted content at the moment across the network, replete with a nice little "new site" alert for Philosophy: https://stackexchange.com/

List of active sites, full sites and betas. Betas have "beta" next to them: https://stackexchange.com/sites

I'm not sure whether consolidating all or parts of it would be useful; I think it probably works as is. The StackExchange home page I'm guessing is designed to help people new to StackExchange find interesting sites by highlighting interesting discussion, so it makes sense that the full list of graduated sites is one click away, i.e. if you're looking for something specific.

As for Area51, I think it's better that new users have to work to find that. This means they participate a little on the network first and get a sense for what a Stack* community is, before starting one/committing to something etc.

Comment: I'm not saying the info is not available. I'm saying it's not easily available for people who are not involved in the community life, for example Area51. These people are the aimed audience, and maybe it could be a good idea to create something to make it easy to know what sites exist. This portal could then be advertised as the place to start for newcomers.

Comment: I just opened the link http://stackexchange.com/sites you put in your answer, and that's actually the kind of page I looked for. Thank you!